# How can I email links to a modal on my webpage?

Tags: modal-dialog

Basically, I want to be able to send a link in email that links to my website that when clicked, it opens the site and the modal I added to the link.  In other words, how can I send a link that will open the modal automatically?

here is my modal I want to open:

```
    <div id="modal-video11" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" align="center">State of the Table Grape Industry with Barry Bedwell</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="videoWrapper">
                <p align="center"><iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PYq5hi5Y9rI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-pnp center-block" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/CaliforniaAgNet">View MORE Videos On Our Youtube Channel!</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

why can't I link it like this? : http://www.americanvineyardmagazine.com/index.html#modal-video11

I also tried using this javascript at the end of my page but it made no difference.  The modal doesn't open:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  if(window.location.href.indexOf('#modal-video11') != -1) {
$('#modal-video11').modal('show');
  }


});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf('#modal-video11') != -1) {
      $('#modal-video11').modal('show');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are posting is correct, but there is a javascript error in that page. You are trying to use jquery ($) in line 143 before loading jquery (line 2001).

If you put that code after loading jquery (at the end), it should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf('#modal-video11') != -1) {
            $('#modal-video11').modal('show');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is correct. Make sure you initialize jQuery before your jQuery script ($)